# Why I am getting copy() expects parameter 2 to be a valid path in PHP

Tags: php, copy, syntax-error

I am trying to copy lets say two files with name `test1234.txt`and `test2431.txt` from a folder to another. I want to copy them and change the filenames to `test1.txt`and `test2.txt`. I wrote a kode for that, but I am getting all the time this error: `Warning: copy() expects parameter 2 to be a valid path, array given in`. Here is the code:

```
$src = glob('C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.date("ymd").'/test*.txt');
$dest = glob('C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/test*.txt');
    foreach ($src as $value) {
        if(preg_match("([0-9]+)", $value)) {
             $arr = array($value);
             foreach($arr as $arrValue) {
             copy($arrValue, $dest);
        }
    }
```

I tried many codes, but I cannot figure out how to eliminate this erroe. Any help is very appreciate.

Comment: Misssing a closing `}`

Comment: You need to pass in a path - you're passing in the output of `glob`, which is an array. I suspect if you want to keep the same filenames, you can just use `copy($arrValue, 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/')`

Comment: Your `foreach($arr as $arrValue)` is not closed. Plus, what @andrewsi said.

Comment: `@andrewsi` I tried your idea, but i get this: `
Warning: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in `

Comment: `@Sergey Vidusov`my `foreach`is closed. I forgot it when I wrote the question.

Comment: @carl - Bah! Then presumably you need an actual filename on the end. You can probably figure out the right filename to use with `pathinfo()`

Comment: @andrewsi Why `pathinfo()`?

Comment: @carl - you can extract the filename from `$arrValue` with it, which is what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: `@andrewsi` `$arrValue`contains the pathinfo. I tried with `echo $arrValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has more that one problem:

```
$src = glob('C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.date("ymd").'/test*.txt');
```

This first line is right, I suppose. It will return an array like this:

> ```
> [
>     C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/160220/test1.txt,
>     C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/160220/test2.txt,
>     C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/160220/test1234.txt
> ]
> ```

```
$dest = glob('C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/test*.txt');
```

This line act like previous line. It will return an array like this:

> ```
> [
>     C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/test1.txt,
>     C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/test2.txt,
>     C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/test1234.txt
> ]
> ```

This means that — if you use this array to set the destination names — **this files will be overwritten**.
Otherwise, if there are not files like `test*.txt` in *Downloads* directory, the array is empty and files cannot be copied.

With this loop you perform a `foreach` loop through all `src` array elements:

```
foreach ($src as $value) {
```

So, following line is completely useless (you retrieve array value by a `glob` with '160220', so **all rows match the `[0-9]+` pattern**:

```
    if(preg_match("([0-9]+)", $value)) 
    {
```

The following lines are incomprensibles: why you assign `$value` to an array to perform a `foreach` loop? The following code can performed simply writing `copy( $value, ... )`.

In other words, when `$value` is `'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/160220/test1234.txt'` (i.e.), the array is `[ 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/160220/test1234.txt' ]`

```
        $arr = array($value);
             foreach($arr as $arrValue) 
        {
             copy($arrValue, $dest);
```

The last line fails anyway, because `$dest` is an array, and you can't set destination value as array. You have to set it to a valid path string.

If you want copy files to a new destination **without overwrite existing files** you have to try in this way:

```
$src        = glob( 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.date("ymd").'/test*.txt' );
$destPrefix = 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/test';

$i = 1;
foreach( $src as $value )
{
    while( file_exists( "{$destPrefix}{$i}.txt" ) ) $i++;
    copy( $value, "{$destPrefix}{$i}.txt" );
}
```

By this way, in the `while` loop, you search if file `Downloads/test1.txt` exists; if they exists, increment `$i` by 1 and search if file `Downloads/test2.txt` exists, etc.. When the filename doesn't exists, you can copy your source to destination.

Otherwise, if you want overwrite existing files, you can act as you original code:

```
$src  = glob( 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.date("ymd").'/test*.txt' );
$dest = glob('C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/test*.txt');
foreach( $src as $key => $value )
{
    copy( $value, $dest[$key] );
}
```

but, if total file number matched in `$dest` are less than `$src` files, your `copy` command will fail.

**Edit:**

1. Please note that with `copy` your original files will not be deleted;
2. If you want copy files preserving their names you can use this command: `copy( $value, 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.basename($value));`

Comment: `@fusion3k` Wow. Thanks. The explication is grandiose..Wow.

Comment: `@fusion3k` It works like a charm. I am/was interested in: **copy files to a new destination without overwrite existing files . Because I don't have these files in the new destination. I liked most the explication and thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

the result of glob is an array so you should use a key to specify a unique value:

```
$src = glob('C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.date("ymd").'/test*.txt');
$dest = glob('C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/test*.txt');
    foreach ($src as $value) {
        if(preg_match("([0-9]+)", $value)) {
             $arr = array($value);
             foreach($arr as $key => $arrValue) {
                copy($arrValue, $dest[$key]);  // <= here
             }
        }
    }
```

if you have no file in the destination do like this:

```
$src = glob('C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.date("ymd").'/test*.txt');
$base_dest = 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/';
    foreach ($src as $value) {
        if(preg_match("([0-9]+)", $value)) {
             $arr = array($value);
             foreach($arr as $arrValue) {
                $info = pathinfo($arrValue);
                $dest = $base_dest . $info['basename'];
                copy($arrValue, $dest);  // <= here
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `@Webinan` I am getting this: **Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in**  and **Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty in**  twice.

Comment: do you have any file with the name you are searching for? if no try the edited code

Comment: @carl but this doesn't change the file name. you can do it by editing `$dest` as you need

Comment: `@Webinan` Now is this: **Notice: Undefined variable: base_dest in

Comment: `@Webinan`what is `$base_dest`?

Comment: did you copy my code? it's defined at the beginning `$base_dest = 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/';`

Comment: `@Webinan` I corrected it. Now I am getting: **Notice: Array to string conversion in. I tried this: `$dest = (string) $base_dest . $info['basename'];`but got same notice.